# mongoid ordering problem

Tags: sorting, model, mongoid

I have been using mongoid for storing data. I have a scenario where I have to sort the parents according the number of dependents they have. My model is simple:

Parent model references_many dependents `stored_as => array`
Dependent model reference_many parents `stored_as => array`

I don't want to loop through the parents, find the number of dependants, store them in an array and dump them into my view.

What I need is to sort the parents according to number of dependants with just one query.
Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to add a field with the count of the number of dependents and keep it up to date with a callback. Something like:

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  references_many :things
  field :thing_count, :type => Integer

  before_update :set_thing_count
  def set_thing_count
    self.thing_count = self.things.count
  end
end
```

Then your sort would just be:

```
MyModel.asc(:thing_count)
```

Mongoid doesn't provide a good querying mechanism for sorts yet, but adding a denormalized count field is pretty easy, and probably better for performance anyways. Hope this helps!